# Using shell script to copy script from one file to another

Tags: shell, sed

Basically I want to copy several lines of code from a template file to a script file.
Is it even possible to use `sed` to copy a string full of symbols that interact with the script?

I used these lines:

```
$SWAP='sudo cat /home/kaarel/template'
sed -i -e "s/#pointer/${SWAP}/" "script.sh"
```

The output is:

```
./line-adder.sh: line 11: =sudo cat /home/kaarel/template: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `$SWAP=...` ==> `SWAP=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this robustly with sed. Just use awk:

```
awk -v swap="$SWAP" '{sub(/#pointer/,swap)}1' script.sh > tmp && mv tmp script.sh
```

With recent versions of GNU awk there's a `-i inplace` flag for inplace editing if that's something you care about.

Good point about "&&". Here's the REALLY robust version that will work for absolutely any character in the search or replacement strings:

```
awk -v old="#pointer" -v new="$SWAP" 's=index($0,old){$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo "abc" | awk -v old="b" -v new="m&&n" 's=index($0,old){$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1'
am&&nc
```

Comment: It worked well except that symbols `&&` from the `template` were replaced in the `script.sh` with `#pointer#pointer`

Comment: I could add this one: `sed -i -e "s/#pointer#pointer/\&\&/g" "script.sh"`...but it would be better to fix the error right away.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the line:

```
$SWAP='sudo cat /home/kaarel/template'
```

The first is that, before executing the line, `bash` performs variable expansion and replaces `$SWAP` with the current value of `SWAP`.  That is not what you wanted.  You wanted `bash` to assign a value to `SWAP`.

The second issue is that the right-hand side is enclosed in single-quotes which protect the string from expansion.  You didn't want to protect the string from expansion: you wanted to execute it.  To execute it, you can use back-quotes which may look similar but act very differently.

Back-quotes, however, are an ancient form of asking for command execution.  The more modern form is `$(...)` which eliminates some problems that back-quotes had.

Putting it all together, use:

```
SWAP=$(sudo cat /home/kaarel/template)
sed -i -e "s/#pointer/${SWAP}/" "script.sh"
```

Be aware, though, that the `sed` command may have problems if there are any sed-active characters in the `template` file.

Comment: Indeed, it solved the problem, but then there's another error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: Unterminated 's' command` . That is the main problem, there are sed-active characters in the `template` file (probably quite a lot). Is there a workaround?